# What happens to Dragon after Donkey & Shrek drank the Happily Ever After potion?

Tags: shrek

Every time after watching *Shrek 2*, I'm disappointed that we don't get to see Dragon while Donkey is transformed into a steed. Is there any information as to what happens to her or what she looks like during that period?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The film's co-Directors toyed with the idea of making Dragon into a pegasus but ultimately decided against it because it didn't really add anything to the film to see her transform.**

---

Quoting from the [Director's Audio Commentary](http://bluray.highdefdigest.com/4164/shrek_whole_story.html) (between co-directors Kelly Asbury and Conrad Vernon):

> *We worked on that a loooong time. I mean, how do we show that that potion affects Fiona as well as Shrek? I mean yeah, big blue flash, yeah one flash. I think there was one point, because Donkey was, Donkey changes into a "noble steed", everyone asks, yeah but we asked ourselves, everyone asked us afterward, '**Who does Dragon change into?'***
>
> *Right*
>
> ***And at one point we did have her change into a Pegasus, a biiig pink horsie with wings ... and I still think offscreen, she's a pegasus somewhere right now, wondering what the heck's going on and flying around...and then she changes back into a dragon before the end of the movie.***

And from the film's Second Audio Commentary (between Producer Aron Warner and editor Michael Andrews):

> *Someone asked me "**what about the Dragon, how come you don't see her transform" and I said "funnily enough, we did do that at one point...but it was just a bit weird to suddenly jump back to the Dragon".***
>
> *Well **yeah, at one point the Dragon was a unicorn or a pegasus with wings.***
>
> *Yeah, she was part of the 'Rescue Team' later in the film but she looked too much like a pretty pony which was fine but it ended up just not hitting me...*

---

As to why they didn't include her in the film until the very end, this is discussed in the film's second commentary. In short, it was because having a  **gigantic fire-breathing dragon** as an ally instantly destroys any sense of suspense in the fim

> *We tried to put her in, several times before but... but you can't have
> her around a lot because she, **'cause she gets everything done. She can
> get through any obstacle.***
>
> *Like we couldn't have her to get into the castle or anything
> like that, or to get those guys out of prison. **It would have just made
> it all too easy.***

Comment: Oh and apologies for the dodgy transcription...

Comment: As opposed to those pegasuses without wings.

Comment: @RogueJedi - One thing I've learned when listening to Director's Commentaries is that they rarely make sense when transcribed verbatim. It's usually just two (or more) people gassing about the film and not really following a script and just rambling along inanely about whatever's happening on the screen in front of them until the movie finishes.

Answer (score 5):

Directly from the [Shrek Wiki](http://shrek.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon), it says that she "was supposed to change into a beautiful female Pegasus, the perfect match to Donkey's transformation into a handsome stallion" it makes me rather sad that was cut :p

Comment: They probably cut it cuz it was kinda sad.  I mean Shrek and Fiona can have their poignant ogre love moment, but Donkey was quite all right with being a horse.  And he'd probably be super psyched about his Pegasus girl.  Instead, it's back to the donkey/dragon life.  His sad story bulldozed by the main hero's happy one.

Comment: Note that the reference is unsourced. Apparently "a couple of kids" asked the director "at a test screening".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing canon however it would stand to reason that she transforms into a horse like donkey

Answer (score -1):

It does say that she was supposed to turn into a beautiful female pegasus while Donkey turned into a handsome stallion but they cut the part of when Dragon turns into a pegasus. I don't actually know why they cut the part of Dragon turning into a pegasus.

Comment: *What* says this? What is the source of this information?