# How does Shrek's rescue party reach him so fast at the end of Shrek 2?

Tags: plot-device, shrek

In the beginning of Shrek 2 it is shown that it takes a long time to reach Far Far Away from Shrek's swamp. Although not explicitly mentioned, from the visuals it seems obvious that the distance is huge, takes a lot of time (the path has snow as well as sunny green meadows) and is possibly dangerous (they have to go through  a snowy mountain edge in one scene)

During the end of the movie Pinochhio, Gingy and the others reach Shrek in what seems like no time at all, after they see his arrest in the magic mirror. Is it explained (or can it be explained using canon logic) how they reached Shrek so fast (and why Shrek, Fiona and Donkey didn't take that path to begin with)? Or is this just a giant plot hole and we are supposed to accept it as it is?

Comment: I honestly only barely remember the scene you're referring to (it's been a long time since I've seen the movie), but I assumed that magic was used by the group. They are, after all, fairy tale beings. Surely some witch or someone could somehow help get them there faster.

Comment: As far as I know the movie doesn't explain it, and magical teleportation only happens in Shrek 3 I think

Comment: There is no evidence to suggest this, but if I had to take a guess, I'd say they could have rode on Dragon.  She DID show up at the end after all.

Comment: Speed of Plot, really. I wouldn't have even been surprised if it were lampshaded in the film.

Comment: Related: [How could Shrek's friends arrive so quickly?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45853/49)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's screenwriter; [David N Weiss](https://twitter.com/DavidNWeiss/status/595010721651433472), they flew there. On Dragon.

[image]

<s>As @zibbobz notes in his comment, we learn in the final scene that Dragon has also traveled to Far Far Away. It's very reasonable to assume that Pinocchio et al were able to fly from Shrek's Swamp to Far Far Away on Dragon, easily explaining how they were able to travel so quickly.</s>

<s>However, I should stress that this is an assumption. I've not located any proof.</s>

Comment: but if they did ride on Dragon, wouldn't she have helped them attack the castle during the "I Need a Hero" song? Instead they had to go and make a giant ginger bread man

Comment: @user13267 - I suspect she was looking after the dronkey babies.

Comment: @user13267, yeah, it's weird, but Dragon does appear after the credits, so the explanation makes sense.

Comment: @user13267  - At the time she was a [heavily pregnant pegasus](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46648/what-happens-to-dragon-after-donkey-shrek-drank-the-happily-ever-after-potion/111603#111603) and wouldn't have been much use to them.